# How to set derby authentication and setup users

Tags: java, authentication, derby

I have the following class but am not sure how to enable authentication and setup users on create.  :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties; 

public class DerbyCreateAndConnect
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String  dbName   = "test7",
               user     = "rss",
               password = "westerly";
       boolean create   =  true;

       Connection conn1 = createAndConnect(dbName, user, password, create);
       Connection conn2 = connectOnly(dbName, "abc", "xyz");
   }
   public static Connection createAndConnect(String dbName, String user,String password, boolean create) {

      Connection conn = null;
      Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
      connectionProps.put("user", user);
      connectionProps.put("password", password); 

      String URL = "jdbc:" + "derby" + ":" + dbName  + ";create = " + create + ";" + connectionProps;

      try{
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);

      }catch(SQLException e){
          System.out.println(e);
          return conn;          
      }                                           

      System.out.println("Created and connected to database " + dbName);
      return conn;
   }
   public static Connection connectOnly(String dbName, String user,String password) {

      Connection conn = null;
      Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
      connectionProps.put("user", user);
      connectionProps.put("password", password); 

      String URL = "jdbc:" + "derby" + ":" + dbName  + ";" + connectionProps;

      try{
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);

      }catch(SQLException e){
          System.out.println(e);
          return conn;          
      }                                           

      System.out.println("Connected to database " + dbName);
      return conn;
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you read through http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/security/cseccsecure42374.html

Answer (score -1):

The method that you will use to create your database needs to be modified as follows:

```
public static Connection createAndConnect(String host, int port, String dbName, String user, String password, boolean create) {

  Connection conn = null;
  Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
  connectionProps.put("user", user);
  connectionProps.put("password", password); 

  String URL = "jdbc:" + "derby" + "://" + host + ":"  + port + "/"  + dbName + ";create = " + create ;

  try{
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
    System.out.println("Created and connected to database " + dbName);
  }catch(SQLException e){
      System.out.println(e);     
  }                                           
  return conn;
}
```

Default port for Derby is 1527, and you must add derbyclient.jat to the project.

Comment: I voted this down for two reasons.  first, it doesn't answer the question and second it is not required.  The code works fine as is it just doesn't require authentication.  this works as an embedded database.